# django synchronize database over REST

Tags: database, django, rest, asynchronous

So I have this 2 applications connected with a REST API (json messages). One written in Django and the other in Php. I have an exact database replica on both sides (using mysql).

My question is, how can i keep this 2 applications databases synchronized?

In other words, when i press "submit" on one of them, i want that data to be saved on the current app database, and on the remote database for the other app using rest.

Is there a django app that does that? i read about django-synchro but didn't see anything REST related.

And i would like to keep things asynchronous, in other words the user must be able to keep using the app while this process is running on the background and keeping data consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at celery and redis and it seems like a cron job will do what i need